# WordPress Ajax загрузка файлов

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, файлы

Добрый день коллеги, возникла необходимость в форме которая отправляется с помощью Ajax переслать файл,
 что увидел c использованием jQuery:
`jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Изменил `processData` на `false`, для отмены конвертации данных, после чего файл отгружается, но теперь возник вопрос
при обращении к `action-у` возвращается 0
Что сообщает о том что данный `action` не зарегистрированный

Но при этом без отключения `processData`, все работает корректно

Я так понимаю что таким образом на back передается `JSON` объект который `WordPress` не может корректно распарсить и определить `action`

Собственно как дальше быть? Как в action передать файл, или может есть способ отдать ajax запрос без регистрации обработчика через `WordPress`?

Ну и собственно сам код

```
    function uploadFile() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var fileInput = $('[type="file"]')[0];

    $.each(fileInput.files, function(key, value) {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: location.origin + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: 'test',
                files: formData
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log('RESPONCE', data);
        });
    return true;
};
```

PHP обработчик

```
function test(){
    if($_FILES){
        echo count($_FILES);
    }else{
        echo 'test';
    }
    die(0);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'test');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'test');
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. "Но при этом без отключения processData, все работает корректно" - в чем вопрос тогда. И где код php?

Comment: При отключенном processData обработчик отрабатывает но при этом FormData преобразуется в строку вида Object FormData что мне как бы не интересно.

Добавил php обработчик, не стал изначально выкладывать поскольку проблема фронта, а в обработчике ничего интересного нетю

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой. Вероятно, сказывается нехватка опыта, но на это убил несколько часов.
Суть такая: передавая данные через ajax не нужно отдельно прописывать action, его необходимо включить в объект FormData:

```js
function uploadFile() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var fileInput = $('[type="file"]')[0];

    $.each(fileInput.files, function(key, value) {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });
    
    formData.append('action', 'test'); // Добавляем action в объект FormData
    
    
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: location.origin + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData, // В качестве data передаем formData
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log('RESPONCE', data);
        });
    return true;
};
```